# examples of shallow and deep copy demonstration in java

Tags: java

```
// shallow copy example
public class a
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        b x = new b(2);
        System.out.println(x.i[0]); // previous value for object x
        System.out.println(x.k);
        b y =(b)x.clone(); // y shallow clone of object x
        y.i[0] = 10; y.k = 999; // changed values in object y
        System.out.println(y.i[0]); // values of y after change
        System.out.println(y.k);

        System.out.println(x.i[0]); // values of x after change     
        System.out.println(x.k);
        System.out.println(x.getClass() == y.getClass()); // both objects belong to same class
        System.out.println(x == y); // both objects are different, they are not the same
    }
}

class b implements Cloneable
{
    public int i[] = new int[1];
    int k;

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }

    b(int j)
    {
        super();
        i[0] = j;
        k = j + 2;
    }
}

/*output

2
4
10
999
10
4
true 
false
*/
//*********************************************************************
//deep copy example

public class a
{     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException 
    {  
        b x = new b(2);
        System.out.println(x.i[0]); // object x values before change
        System.out.println(x.k);

        b y = (b)x.clone(); // deep clone y of object x

        System.out.println(y.i[0]); // values of object y
        System.out.println(y.k);

        System.out.println(x.i[0]); // values of object x after changing the values of the members in object y in clone method  
        System.out.println(x.k);
        System.out.println(x.getClass() == y.getClass());
        System.out.println(x==y);
    }
}

class b implements Cloneable
{
    public int i[] = new int[1];
    int k;

    public Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        b t = new b(6);
        return t;
    }

    b(int j)
    {
        i[0] = j;
        k = j+2;
    }
}

/*

2
4
6
8
2
4
true 
false
*/
```

I have already written the examples please see if I left out anything.I have to give a demo regarding it and wanted it to be as simple as possible.Do let me know if I can make it even simpler.
I have provided quotes wherever they changed values or object was being cloned.

Comment: Demos should be pretty; please indent consistently.

Comment: Probably better posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can u give me a direct link if possible...in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A golden tip for demos: use meaningful class names and variable names, and make the examples more concrete. Use for example a `Book` class and an `Author` class

```
public class Book{
  private String title;
  private Author author;
...
}
public class Author{
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

With a getter/setter (or public fields even) you can do a deep/shallow clone of a `Book` instance, and illustrate what changes when you change the name of the `Author`. Exactly the same as what you did, but easier to tell to an audience, and easier for an audience to follow since everybody knows what a book and an author is and does not need to look at the code to follow your explanation

Comment: Thanks I got an idea from what you mentioned.........But using String is not good for shallow copy example as it will anyway copy it as another object thought it is reference type since strings are immutable that's why had to resort to this.. lol

Comment: Therefore I said yo use the `Author` to refer to. You can always change the title to for example `int ISBNNumber` if you prefer working with int's. As long as it is understandable for your audience

Comment: Yeah :) agree with you...Thank you for your time :)